# Can not display stacks or Push

Tags: c++, stack

So I have a project for my C++ class and we are asked to create a library program using Stacks and Doubly Linked Lists. Now we cannot use the stack header file so everything from push, pop, display, etc. has to created by us.

I have the push function working, but the display function I cannot seem to get it to display more than just the lastNode stuct. When it tries to access previousNode, it crashes. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Also I can not get the pop function to work either. The program crashes as well when it runs.

```
void pushBook(BookStack *bkStack, BookNode *bkNode)
{
    if(isEmpty(bkStack))
      {
        bkStack->lastNode = bkNode;
        bkStack->lastNode->previousNode = NULL;
      }
    else
    {
        bkStack->lastNode->previousNode = bkStack->lastNode;
        bkStack->lastNode = bkNode;
    }
}
BookNode *popBook(BookStack *bkStack)
{
  BookNode *temp = new BookNode;
  if(isEmpty(bkStack))
  {
    temp = bkStack->lastNode;
    return temp;
  }
  else if(bkStack->lastNode->previousNode == NULL)
  {
    temp = bkStack->lastNode;
    bkStack->lastNode = NULL;
    return temp;
  }else
  {
    temp = bkStack->lastNode->previousNode;
    bkStack->lastNode->previousNode = NULL;
    bkStack->lastNode = temp;
    return temp;
  }
}

void displayStackElements(BookStack *bkStack)
{
  BookNode *nodePtr = new BookNode;

  nodePtr = bkStack->lastNode;

  if(isEmpty(bkStack))
  {
    cout << "Book stack is empty." << endl;
  }
  else
  {
      while(nodePtr != NULL)
        {
          cout << "\nBook Name: " << nodePtr->bk.name << endl;
          cout << "Author Name: " << nodePtr->bk.authorName << endl;
          cout << "Page Numbers: " << nodePtr->bk.pagesNumber << endl;
          cout << "ISBN: " << nodePtr->bk.isbn << endl;
          cout << endl;


          nodePtr = bkStack->lastNode->previousNode;
          }
      }

}
bool isEmpty(BookStack *bkStack)
{
    bool status;

    if(bkStack->lastNode == NULL)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}

void addBook(BookStack *bkStack)
{
  BookNode *bkNode = new BookNode;
  cout << "\nEnter the book name: ";
  getline(cin, bkNode->bk.name);
  cout << "Enter the Author's Name: ";
  getline(cin, bkNode->bk.authorName);
  cout << "Enter the ISBN: ";
  cin >> bkNode->bk.isbn;
  cout << "Enter the page numbers: ";
  cin >> bkNode->bk.pagesNumber;
  pushBook(bkStack, bkNode);
}

void removeBook(BookStack *bkStack)
{
  BookNode *removedNode = new BookNode;
  removedNode = popBook(bkStack);

  if(removedNode == NULL)
  {
    cout << "\nNo books to remove." << endl;
  }else
  {
    cout << endl << removedNode->bk.name << " was removed." << endl;
  }
}
```

(edit) Sorry about that here's the structs from the main header file

```
    struct Book
        {
            int isbn;
            string name;
            string authorName;
            int pagesNumber;
        };

    struct BookNode
        {
            Book bk;
            BookNode *previousNode;
        };

    struct BookStack
        {
            BookNode *lastNode = NULL;
        };
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `bkStack->lastNode->previousNode` is always the same thing. Do you mean `nodePtr->previousNode`?

Comment: are you talking about within the popBook function? if so, then I guess. I really don't know. The teacher did not really explain this subject all too well, and I have looked to videos and read some about it. Like I under a little on how doing things this way works, but implementing that ideology is still troublesome with me.

Comment: @SamuelO'Neal _"The teacher did not really explain this subject all too well ..."_ For the _vast_ number of cases, it's the other way round. You didn't well understand what your teacher was telling you. (Just a side note)

Comment: Can you show us the push fonction ?

Comment: @Nico I added the push function back to the original post

Comment: Show us the IsEmpty function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done c++ in a while so if any of the statement below are wrong, tell me so !

Here what I see :

In `displayStackElements`:

`nodePtr = bkStack->lastNode->previousNode;` should be `nodePtr = nodePtr->previousNode;` otherwise, you will always display the previousnode of lastnode of bkStack in an infinite loop !

---

I don't know why you do this everywhere:

```
BookNode *nodePtr = new BookNode;
nodePtr = bkStack->lastNode;
```

You don't need a new BookNode if you are assigning it right after it ! You are creating a new BookNode in memory and then overwrite the pointer. This is a memory leak. You can simply do this:

```
BookNode *nodePtr = bkStack->lastNode;
```

---

In your pop function, the last else code should be this. You want to pop out the lastnode, not the previous node of the current last node.

```
temp = bkStack->lastNode->previousNode;
BookNode *lastNode = bkStack->lastNode
bkStack->lastNode->previousNode = NULL;
bkStack->lastNode = temp;
return lastNode;
```

---

In your push function, you are setting the previousNode of last node but after that, you were overwriting the lastNode with the node passed in parameter. Your list became broken because the lastNode->previousNode will always be emtpy. The else statement should be this.

```
bkNode->previousNode = bkStack->lastNode;
bkStack->lastNode = bkNode;
```

Comment: The program still closes on me.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! It also makes sense now to me.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't show the `BookNode` class definition or its constructor, I can only assume that you forget to clear the nodes `previousNode` pointer, which means that after you add the second second node then `bkStack->lastNode->previousNode` will be an uninitialized pointer.

Dereferencing uninitialized pointers leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).